How to use Python argparse to have lazily loaded subcommands
I have a python package with a lot of sub commands and sub-sub commands. It is organized somewhat like this:
main.py
import argparse

from sum import prepare_arg_parser as prepare_sum_parser
from sub import prepare_arg_parser as prepare_sub_parser

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sub_parsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command", required=True)

prepare_sum_parser(sub_parsers.add_parser("sum"))
prepare_sub_parser(sub_parsers.add_parser("sub"))

args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)

sum.py
import argparse


def prepare_arg_parser(parser):
    parser.set_defaults(func=do_sum)
    parser.add_argument("a", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("b", type=int)


def do_sum(args):
    print(f"{args.a} + {args.b} = {args.a + args.b}")

and so on.
However, as the list of module grows, the startup time also loads.
I would like to lazily load each sub commands, so it only loads what's needed for the selected command.
I tried something like this:
import argparse

def do_sum(args):
    from sum import prepare_arg_parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    prepare_arg_parser(parser)
    sum_args = parser.parse_args(args)
    sum_args.func(sum_args)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sub_parsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command", required=True)

sub_parsers.add_parser("sum").set_defaults(func=do_sum)

args, rest = parser.parse_known_args()
args.func(rest)

But then the help and error texts are not right.
Another way would be to split each sub commands into a "prepare argparse" module which would know all the args but lazily call the do_sum function for example, but I don't like it as it separate the argument declaration from their use. Also it would still load a lot of unnecessary files.
Is there have lazily-loaded sub commands?

the main culprit is the line from sum import prepare_arg_parser as prepare_sum_parser, when this line executes your subcommand is loaded, the only way to not load the command is to have it in another file, you can write system for this to make it look nicer but there is no escape

bottom line, consider something else than argparse, like click

Simple Approach
The cost of creating parser and sub parsers is cheap comparing to the cost of importing many modules. My approach to this problem is to create the parser and sub parsers in main.py and leave the real actions in the modules.
Let start with the main module:
# main.py
import argparse
import importlib


def parse_command_line():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    sub_parsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command", required=True)

    sum_parser = sub_parsers.add_parser("sum")
    sum_parser.add_argument("a", type=int)
    sum_parser.add_argument("b", type=int)

    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_command_line()
    command = importlib.import_module(args.command)
    command.main(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

In this module, we created the parser and one sub parser (sum). We can add more sub parsers later.
After we parsed the command line, the args.command contain the name of the parser, e.g. "sum". The plan is to have a module with that name, i.e. sum.py. Within that module, we should have a function main() which carries out the action:
# sum.py
import argparse

def main(args: argparse.Namespace):
    print(f"{args.a} + {args.b} = {args.a + args.b}")

What I like about this approach:

We don't import all the modules, only the one we need. That means quick load time.
All the command-line handling are in one place, making it easier to read and to troubleshoot.
As we add more modules, only parse_command_line() function grows, the main() function remains the same.
The code in each of the module is simpler: each module only need to implement a main() function and not worrying about parsing the command line.

What I don't like:

When we add a new module, we need to edit in two places: the module itself, and in the parse_command_line() function
If we only have a couple of modules, this approach does not offer much in term of performance gain

Plugin Approach
In this approach, let's establish a simple "plugin" system. Besides the main module, we have plugins, each plugin will satisfy these requirements:

The file name should in the format sub_<name>.py. For examples: sub_sum.py, sub_dbl.py, ...
Each plugin will parse the command line and perform some action.

Let's start with the main module:
# main.py
import argparse
import pathlib
import subprocess
import sys


def parse_command_line():
    # Determine the choices
    main_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
    choices = [
        path.stem.removeprefix("plugin_") for path in main_dir.glob("plugin_*.py")
    ]

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("command", choices=choices)

    return parser.parse_known_args()


def main():
    args, remainder = parse_command_line()
    command = [sys.executable, f"plugin_{args.command}.py"] + remainder
    subprocess.run(command)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Here is the content of the "sum" plugin:
# plugin_sum.py
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("a", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("b", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(f"{args.a} + {args.b} = {args.a + args.b}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

So how does it work? The main module only collect the names of the plugins and invoke the correct plugin using subprocess.run(). Each plugin is an independent script, capable of running on its own.
What I like:

Adding more module (plugin) does not require changes in the main module
Each plugin is an independent script, which makes it easier to test

What I don't like:

For the main script, the --help flag does not offer much help because it has no knowledge of the plugins
Each plugin has to do the command-line parsing on its own

Conclusion
I like the simple approach better for its simplicity. The plugin approach works better for more complex structure. Both approaches will not load all the modules in order to work.

Thanks, this helps a bit, but I'm not ready to move all of my argument declarations into a single file. And the plugin approach is just like my own attempt, it doesn't work with the help and error messages.
